# "Cannot update project reference" error introduced by Visual Studio 2012

Tags: build, build-process, visual-studio-2012

I had a command line build which was working fine with Visual Studio 2010.

I am now trying the same solution with Visual Studio 2012.

When I build it via the command line:

```
devenv MediaPlayer.sln /build "Release|Any CPU"
```

I get a pile of errors with the website:

> 37>------ Build started: Project: C:...\Web\, Configuration: Debug
>   Any CPU ------
>
> 37>Cannot update project reference ''. Source project
>   not available.Cannot update project reference ''. Source project not
>   available.Cannot update project reference ''. Source project not
>   available.Cannot update project reference ''. Source project not
>   available.Cannot update project reference ''. Source project not
>   available.Cannot update project reference ''. Source project not
>   available.Cannot update project reference ''. Source project not
>   available.Cannot update project reference ''. Source project not
>   available.Cannot update project reference ''. Source project not
>   available.Cannot update project reference ''. Source project not
>   available.Cannot update project reference ''. Source project not
>   available.Validating Web Site

But then I open the SAME solution in Visual Studio 2012, and build it. It builds.

I then run this same build via the command line, and it builds.

So I check it in, and let the build process fetch it into the build directory, and I get THE SAME ERRORS.

At this point, I'm stumped as to what to do next. Any pointers?

Comment: I'm making progress on this problem thanks to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435747/web-site-in-solution-where-rebuild-solution-compile-succeeds-cannot-launch-deb?lq=1

Comment: It is unclear how (or whether) this is related, but I got this to go away by disabling "Lightweight Solution Load" in VS2017.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the Visual Studio 2012 build output says

> Cannot update project reference

It's actually saying

> Something went wrong, and you know what?
>
> I'm not going to tell you what it is!
>
> BWAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA

After a full days search, it came down to a third party library (Castle.Windsor.dll) not being in the .bin directory. I don't know why this problem showed up with Visual Studio 2012 and not Visual Studio 2010. My guess is that in Visual Studio 2010, this was automatically copied over because it was a dependency of another project the website was dependent on.

I manually created a `.refresh` file for `Castle.Windsor.dll` and `Castle.Core.dll`, and now it builds.

Answer (score 3):

I also experienced this same error when trying to build a solution in VS 2012.

I had a solution that I upgraded from VS 2010 to VS 2012 and then started removing some long dead projects. VS 2012 became "confused" with this removal and deemed that a website project in the solution needed a reference to '', which was not available.

To resolve this, I undid the above mentioned changes to the solution, opened it up in VS 2010, removed the long dead projects and built successfully and then closed VS 2010. I was then able to open/update the solution in VS 2012 and work without issue.